# Notify user for document signing after embedded signing

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I am trying to embed docusign api to my application for signing documents from two parties. Until now I have been able to use the docusign "Request a signature through your app (embedded signing)" to allow a specific individual to sign the document through my app.

Now I want to add an additional user's email, who will be notified via email when the first user completes the signing procedure to sign his part of the document.

In the code, I have tried to add a second recipient/signer:

```js
    const signer2 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
        email: "blah@blah.com",
        name: "Blah",
        clientUserId: "blah",
        recipientId: 2,
        routingOrder: "2",
    });
```

add his tabs:

```js
    const signHere2 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/sn2/",
        anchorYOffset: "-10",
        anchorUnits: "pixels",
        anchorXOffset: "0" });

    const signer2Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        signHereTabs: [signHere2] });
    signer2.tabs = signer2Tabs;
```

and add this signer to the recipients list:

```js
    const recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
        signers: [signer1, signer2],
    });
    env.recipients = recipients;
```

The first signer is able to sign the document embedded through my app and complete the process. However, the second signer never receives the email for signing his part when the first one completes. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **clientUserId** from the second signer like this:

```
   const signer2 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
        email: "blah@blah.com",
        name: "Blah",
        recipientId: 2,
        routingOrder: "2",
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, anytime